# How to import sample project xml files into ServiceNow Developer Instance?

Tags: servicenow

Currently, I am half way through the learning path. If anyone can share the steps it would be very useful for me.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: I have a sys_remote_update_set.xml file which contains info like tables, categories, etc. which has been created using ServiceNow. I need to import it in my dev instance. If I give File -> Import from Source Control , then it is asking for Repository URL. So, how I can import this xml file ?

Comment: https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/london-platform-administration/page/administer/development-best-practices/task/t_ImportARecordAsXMLData.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Go the left navigation in dev instance and search "Retrieved Update Sets" and click on it.
   [image: Retrieved Update Sets]
2. After opening Retrieved Update Sets the list of record and click "Import Update Set from XML" related link.
   [image: Click "Import Update Set from XML" related link]
3. After that select, your update set XML file and load.
4. After the load, the XML file, open uploaded on and "Preview update set" after that commit that update set.
   [image: Preview]

[image: Commit]

Regards,

Prins Kumar Gupta